# Trouble using Newton's Method on $6$th root of $2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

first post here.

I've been reading a calculus text for the last few months and have stumbled into a problem that I cannot find an answer to after all my researching.

I am having trouble understanding this specific statement in *Calculus Early Transcedentals*

"First we observe that finding the $6$th root of $2$ is equivalent to finding the positive root of the equation $x^6 - 2 =0$"

I do not understand how we get $x^6 - 2 =0$ from $6$th root of $2$

It is from a chapter involving Newton's method for finding roots, which I think I am understanding quite well otherwise. Might just be a major hole in my understanding of algebra.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the quantity we try to find.

$$x=\sqrt[6]2$$

$$x^6 = 2$$

$$x^6-2=0$$

Comment: great makes perfect sense, thanks

Comment: In particular there are two roots of that equation. Only the positive one is what you want to find.